# Couchbase on Amazon EC2. Connection from .NET SDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase

I am trying to connect to couchbase running on Amazon EC2. I can connect it by public URL exposed from Amazon or IP address, but every time I try to connect from the code, it throws a timeout exception.

What I have done is:
I set a configuration

```
<couchbaseClients>
<couchbase useSsl="false">
  <servers>
    <add uri="http://PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS:8091/pools"></add>
  </servers>
  <buckets>
    <add name="default" useSsl="false" password="">
      <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5"></connectionPool>
    </add>
  </buckets>
</couchbase>
```

Then while opening cluster I put there a configuration name

```
 new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase");
```

Also, I found somewhere I need to open a set of ports. I did inbound rules for all the ports I found to allow for all clients (any IP address).

What am I doing wrong?

Exception is:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS:11210
```

Port 11210 is opened, I'm able to telnet.
Also, I am able to connect to couchbase`s console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the resolution was quite simple. During installation of Couchbase i was wrongly specifying Server Hostname - a local one

Comment: I have the exact same problem (or at least it seems to be). What did you specify in Hostname? The AWS Public IP/DNS? with the Port? (Because those give me an error in the couchbase console)

Comment: Two things: 1. In hosts file of vm map public hostname with private ip. 2. In hostname set the public host of ur VM.  p.s. Dont forgett to open ports

Comment: the public hostname is the public DNS/IP from amazon, the private ip would be the one i obtain from the VM itself?

Comment: All of the info you may see in the VM settings UI on AWS. Public hostname is public DNS  - blablabla.compute-1.amazonaws.com, Public and Private IP`s you may also find on the same page (Description tab).

Comment: It worked putting the private ip in the hostname but now I get 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond' **bummer**   , thanks for the help though

Comment: Well, it used to work as i described. Be sure u changesd hosts file as i suggest. Have required ports opened in aws settings and then put public dns  address in hostname of couchbase.

Comment: It worked! I added the info in your answer for anyone else to see easily if they happen upon the same issue. Thanks a lot! (And feel free to re-edit as you see fit)